# AltDS - Where is the alternate data stream stored physically on the disc?

Tags: ads, ntfs, alternate-data-stream

I'm struggling to find any information on the physical location of ADS data. Is it stored within the NTFS MFT or does the MFT point to a second location?

Answer (score 1):

ADS are real NTFS streams. The only difference between ADS and "normal" streams is that ADS are named streams, "normal" streams don't have a name. ADS like "normal" streams are located in the MFT.